# wget relative url to absolute url in shell

Tags: shell, wget

Hi I am using wget to copy a data from url and store it in a file.The url gives me a aspx file .I need to convert the aspx file to html file.SO I renamed the file from asd.aspx to asd.html.But in my file there are relative url which are not working in  my html file.They should point to original url.How can i convert the relative url to their absolute url.Is there any way  to achieve this,

for example

```
in original file link is 

href='../../login.html'
```

but when i open the html file in my browser the link is changed to

```
href="localhost/login.html"

but it should be

href="abc.com/login.html"
```

I hope i have clear the prob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add `<base href="http://www.abc.com/original/path">` in the head section of the html file, wget will not rewrite the links automatically.

Comment: this means i need to edit the file everytime.This wget is in a shell script whcih runs periodically

Comment: this edit can be done automatically, for instance when you rename the aspx to html you could have:

$originalpath="http://www.abc.com/original/path" ;
echo '<base href="'$originalpath'">' > file.html ;
cat file.aspx >> file.html

... browsers are tolerant about a <base> tag outside the <head>

Comment: actually it will rewrite - as pike says (other answer) you can use the -k/--convert-links option in wget, which is probably a better solution in this case

Answer (score 12):

the -k option in wget will convert urls after wget is done retrieving files. links to files that have not been retrieved will point to their remote url, links to files that have been retrieved to their local version.

http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/wget/wget_11.html

Comment: Will not work if file is not recognized as a supported file type (ssi in my case)